# How can I prevent duplicate keys when adding data to an object array?

Tags: javascript

I have some code where I am looping through some records in a table, and whilst doing this I'm organising this data into a JavaScript object array.

For example the data below.

[image]

I need to ensure that if a record "Name" has already been recorded, then rather than create a new item it uses the existing item so that the end result will be an object or array like this:

```
{
    "bobjones": {
         "sessions": 7
    },
    "annfrank": {
         "sessions": 4
    },
    "fredsmith": {
         "sessions": 4
    }
}
```

Doing this in PHP is easy, but I'm struggling with this in JS due to the way keys are interpreted. Could somebody provide some direction?

Comment: Could you provide input data?

Comment: An array would call for some brackets, where you have all braces. Was that a mistake in your example or is that a single array element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Your object seems malformed. It's make much more sense to have something more like `[{name:'bobjones', sessions:'7'},...]`. *I'm organising this data into a JavaScript object array* I see an object, I don't see an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const inputData = [
  { name: 'Bob Jones', date: '----', session: 1 },
  { name: 'Ann Frank', date: '----', session: 1 },
  { name: 'Bob Jones', date: '----', session: 1 },
  { name: 'Fred Smith', date: '----', session: 1 },
]

var outputData = {}
for(let doc of inputData) {
  if(outputData[doc.name]) {
    outputData[doc.name].session = outputData[doc.name].session + doc.session
  } else {
    outputData[doc.name] = doc
  }
}

console.log(outputData)
```

Now outputData is:

```
{ 'Bob Jones': { name: 'Bob Jones', date: '----', session: 2 },
  'Ann Frank': { name: 'Ann Frank', date: '----', session: 1 },
  'Fred Smith': { name: 'Fred Smith', date: '----', session: 1 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just test to see if the object property exists. If so, add to its `sessions` property, if not, set it.

```
if(obj[prop]) {
    obj[prop].sessions += sessions;
} else {
    obj[prop] = { sessions };
}
```

In the first if statement, if you're concerned that `obj[prop]` may exist but `obj[prop].sessions` may not, you can change it to `if(obj[prop] && obj[prop].sessions) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, assuming that you input data is an array of objects (since, that is generally how you get data when consulting a database).

```js
const table = [
    {name: "Bob Jones", date: "12-12-2019", sessions: 3},
    {name: "Ann Frank", date: "12-9-2019", sessions: 4},
    {name: "Bob Jones", date: "12-9-2019", sessions: 2},
    {name: "Fred Smith", date: "12-9-2019", sessions: 4}
];

let res = table.reduce((res, {name, date, sessions}) =>
{
    if (res[[name]])
        res[[name]].sessions += sessions;
    else
        res[[name]] = {sessions: sessions};

    return res;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```